# Acknowledgement number of an RST packet

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, wireshark, sockets

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735618/tcp-rst-packet-details) states that the acknowledgement number of an RST packet should be 0, but I have found it to be other than 0 when I captured some HTTP packets using Wireshark.

So when does the acknowledgement number of an RST packet contains a value other than 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acknowledgement number is completed when the packet is an acknowledgement to a previous packet.  In this case, the ACK bit is set.

You can have an ACK packet, that is also an RST packet.  It both ACKnowledges a previous packet, and signals that the TCP session should be reset.

This is called an RST/ACK packet (simply because the ACK and RST bits are set).